# Running gather table statistics multiple times inside a package causes Performance Issues

Tags: oracle, plsql, table-statistics

We have a big package that ALWAYS encounters performance issues. We get an average of 6-10 tickets raised for this issue in a month. Sometimes the program would run successfully for minutes, sometimes it would run for days just to Error out with an unexplained error.

I started to look deeper into this and found there are a number of possible causes of the performance issues, such as numerous un-tuned SQLs and bad coding practice, etc.

One thing that struck me today is in the code, it's calling Gather Table Statistics multiple times, in multiple places before doing some big operation (such as a huge Select Statement and a lot of DML statements).

This program is run on a daily, weekly and monthly basis, depending on the organization's practices.

Unfortunately, I am unable to replicate the performance issue to know more about this, but I am guessing running Gather Table statistics to multiple tables, multiple times, can cause major performance issues in the program. I am unable to find any resources to back this idea up. Can someone confirm?

Comment: How quickly does your data change? Is your data static and the statistics will hardly ever change? Or are the tables dropped/truncated and then new data created so that the statistics will be significantly different in every execution?

Comment: The tables being gathered act like temporary tables. The tables don't get dropped, but they do get inserted with a wide range of data (from 0-777k), and then DELETED afterwards. I've seen some runs where it processed 48k records successfully in 1 hour, and then another run where it failed for the same number of records after running for 4 days.

Comment: "The tables being gathered act like temporary tables." Why don't you use temporary tables then? It sounds like you are going to generate a lot of undo data with your current method.

Comment: unfortunately this code has been here longer than I have, and i just basically got here around a year ago. I think the reason they didn't utilize a real temporary table is because there's an option not to purge the data (for debugging purposes or whatnot). @MT0

Comment: You could always create table(s) with `n` partitions (where `n` is greater than the number of times your program will be running simultaneously) and store all the data for that program run in that partition and then when the run is done then drop the partition. You can store the current partition number using a cyclic sequence and just get the next sequence number at the start of each run.

Comment: unfortunately, any big change is off the table for now, as they're hesitant to do anything that can possibly impact thousands of customers. But i'll definitely take this into consideration @MT0

Answer (score 1):

Yes, can confirm, have seen code that spends 80% of the runtime gathering stats. Given your constraints, I'd try, in the following order:

1. I'd have a look at the `DELETE` statements to check if they can be replaced by `TRUNCATE TABLE`.
2. Gather stats once the tables are filled, [lock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_STATS.html#GUID-77225DE6-28D1-4064-9531-87BB1CFB4405) their stats and comment out any other `gather_table_stats` calls. The assumption is that the data will not differ widely enough from day to day or week to week to cause different query plans.
3. If that doesn't work, I'd try to have a look at [`DBA_TAB_MODIFICATIONS`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS.html) to at least check if the tables have been changed enough since the last stats gathering.